# Extjs 6: How to forcefully show a tooltip on an element on a button click?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a scenario i.e.combobox and a button. I want to show a tooltip on combox when I click on a button and hide it when i click again. How do I do that without using ids on tooltip instance? Also can I specify the position of tooltip i.e x and y relative to combobox and style tooltip a little bit?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on button create new tooltip instance as below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    html:<tip contents>,
    id:<some id>
});
```

And `showBy()` this instance for that combo like `tip.showBy(<combo instance>)`.
Now again you click on button you check if tip instance is present, if yes then hide it else show it again. But you will need some id for tooltip.

Comment: Yes you can, you can make use of query selector by giving some css name.Like for ex. if you use cls:'myTip', then you can get tip's instance by below line :
Ext.query('div.myTip')
It will return you instance.From it you can get tooltip component.
Note Ext.query() returns array.Reply if any issues.

Comment: Thanks..But do i need to specify the id of the combo (while creating id) or i can just get the id of the combobox by queryselector and use that id to render tooltip to? Just asking because not a big fan of ids.

Comment: Use id for combo for its instance.Yes you can use queryselector.